# Samsung S7: stuttering during slow motion video recording

Tags: camera, performance, samsung-galaxy-s7, video-recording

When I try to record slow-motion video on a Samsung S7 (running Android 7.0), [there is often stuttering](https://youtu.be/HZifpoYi0Mk). This has ruined some otherwise amazing footage I acquired.

What can I do to ensure that there will be no stuttering?

So far I have tried:

- Recording to internal storage instead of the SD card (although the card I use, SanDisk SDSDQXP-032G, is rated for 90 MB/s write)
- Making sure that "Power saving" is off
- Closing all apps (using the Overview button, then Close All)

The stuttering will occasionally noticeable even when not recording video, just having the camera app open in slow-motion mode and quickly moving the phone from side to side. Of course, it is harder to notice it this way because everything is happening much faster than during slow-motion playback.

Note: I am making fairly long recordings, with playback times as long as 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue on my Samsung Galaxy S7 (Exynos).
The stuttering in slow-motion video is awful and there is nothing I can do about it.

I have also tried without SD-card, no difference.

The best way is to minimize the number of installed apps. It will not remove stuttering completely, but might reduce it a little bit. It is somehow the intrinsic structure of Android OS that apps are always running or in standby, i.e. consuming memory and some small amount of CPU power. Any, even the slightest, extra CPU load will cause massive stuttering.